# Playing a .gif file with html

Tags: html

i started yesterday with html and I have issue. Everytime I try to open it in the website it shows just a black thing. This is the code:

```
<img src="Users\mkotz\OneDrive\Desktop\Eternity.gif"height="450"width="150" 
                loop="true"
                autoplay="true">
```

[image]

Comment: Check browser console and make sure that the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be alright with the code but the path you are referring to might be invalid. You should be considering using a path referring to the website and further its files.

In web development you should folder all your files something like this:

[image]

Add your image files always to the resources folder. Then you can refer to it from the index.html by saying `src="./resources/<image_name>.gif"` and so on.

Comment: It didn‘t worked

Answer (score -1):

The link is probably invalid, Check that and try again.